# C/C++ Macro definition to choose what program should run

Tags: c++, c, macros

Let's say I have this program:

```
int main(){
    printf("program 1\n");
}

int main(){
    printf("program 2\n");
}
```

How can I define a macro that would help me to choose which of the mains will run?

Ideally I'd like to define something as 1 (or 2) and "program 1" (or "program 2") should be printed.

Comment: That's not legal code afaik. Having 2 mains is almost definitely an error. Can't you just pass in an argument to the main that specifies which part of the program to run?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this? Having 2 mains is an error and should be equivalent to have 2 distinct programs

Comment: I could, but I'd like to know if this is possible. There's some interesting macro tricks I've seen so far. I'm just doing this to test some codes that should do the same thing

Comment: can downvoters explain?

Comment: The problem with macros is that they get resolved on compile time. if you take a look at Barmar's example, you'll see that either the first main or the second main will be compiled, but not both. A far better solution would be to parse the command line arguments and depending on them the main function should decide which sub-function to call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `#if` around the `main()` functions.

```
#if WHICHMAIN == 1
int main(){
    printf("program 1\n");
}
#endif

#if WHICHMAIN == 2
int main(){
    printf("program 2\n");
}
#endif
```

You can then compile the program with `-DWHICHMAIN=1` or `-DWHICHMAIN=2` to specify the value of the macro.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I usually do: I create a configuration file called `my_config.h`, and define macro in it, for example, `#define TEST_MODE`.

And the code is like this:

```
#include "my_config.h"
int main() {
    #ifdef TEST_MODE
    return test_main();
    #else
    return real_main();
    #endif
}
```